# How can I use Socket.IO to create new markers and interact with them?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, leaflet

I am able to click on the map and make new markers realtime, but when I move the first marker the second one disappears, how can I keep making new markers, not lose them and interact with them?

How can I reference the correct marker?

```
<script>
        var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

        L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
            maxZoom: 20,
            attribution: 'Leaflet'
        }).addTo(map);
        map.attributionControl.setPrefix('');

        var markers = [];

        map.on('click', addMarker);

        function addMarker(e) {
            socket.emit('marker event', e.latlng)
        }

        socket.on('marker event', function (msg) {

            console.log(msg)
            marker = L.marker([msg.lat, msg.lng], { draggable: 'true' }).addTo(map);
            markers.push([marker._latlng.lat, marker._latlng.lng])

            marker.on('dragend', function (e) {
                console.log(e.target._latlng)
                socket.emit('drag marker', e.target._latlng)
            });

            socket.on('drag marker', function (msg) {
                console.log('RTC drag')
                marker.setLatLng([msg.lat, msg.lng])
            })

        })

    </script>
```

Comment: Scope issue. Read up on `let` vs `const` vs `var`, and on javascript closures.

Comment: I think the issue is that I can't reference the correct marker and it only controls the last one that is created.